# Migrating database with heroku pg:pull in detached state

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm using the [Heroku CLI pg:pull](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-pull-source-target) command to migrate a `Heroku Postgres` connected database from one Heroku app (`my-source-app`) to another (`my-target-app`) - both of which are in my control.

First, I clear the database on the target application;

```
heroku pg:reset -a my-target-app
```

Then initiate the pg:pull

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE $(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my-target-app) --exclude-table-data='table5;table9' -a my-source-app
```

It seems to start working (transferring schema then data table-by-table), but is very slow. The original db is ~20GB; large, but not unreasonable. If I monitor the size of the target database (via the Heroku dashboard) it seems to fill at only about 35MB/minute.

My questions;

1. Is this command routing the data through my local machine or is it direct machine-to-machine?
2. Is there a way to "detach" from the process, and later monitor it (as I can with Heroku's [run:detached](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run-detached) command) so I don't need to remain online for the duration?
3. Is there a better approach for migrating the data here (such as creating a follower and switching it over to the new app somehow; I've tried this without success)

Answer (score 0):

Answering the specific questions;

1. The data was *not* copied via my local machine while running the command.
2. In the end, I remained connected while the `pg:pull` operation completed; there doesn't seem to be a way to detach.
3. A similar feature (which copies everything across) is `pg:copy` - see [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#direct-database-to-database-copies)  - which was a viable alternative here.